# Using json objects retrieved by post angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, post

I have a post that posts on page load. it returns json. how do i then use this json on the page to display images and text based on the object.

is there a way to hold the value of the objects in scope in angular

**My post on page load**

```
$scope.GetData = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.somepage.co.uk/page/page2/objects",
            method: "POST",
            date: {},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('you have received the data ');
            console.log(response);
        }, function (response) { // optional
            // failed
            console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    $scope.GetData();
```

I would like if I could store the objects in different scopes so that I may use them on the page.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

here is the object I need to turn into scopes

```
data
:
Array(1)
0
:
c_name
:
"ben"
d_text
:
[]
max_slots
:
2
resolution
:
(2) [1920, 1080]
slots
:
Array(3)
0
:
{path_image: "", base_image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…O7/aaFdrXd6na2UApSIJEwod/rWVlSUUk2h2Gbknfi6P/2Q==", slot_id: 1}
1
:
{path_image: "", base_image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…O7/aaFdrXd6na2UApSIJEwod/rWVlSUUk2h2Gbknfi6P/2Q==", slot_id: 2}
2
:
{path_image: "", base_image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…O7/aaFdrXd6na2UApSIJEwod/rWVlSUUk2h2Gbknfi6P/2Q==", slot_id: 3}
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__v
:
0
_id
:
"59c92d6f45b79c8c110ee6ab"
```

Comment: `$scope.images = response.images; $scope.text = response.text;`

Comment: Thanks, would that be the success response on the post ? its easy when you know how. thanks again

Comment: Use a controller for this purpose. You can add a controller to the HTML page and reference properties of this controller by adding them to `this` inside the controller. For instance `<div ng-controller=MyController as controller>` and set the image in the controller `this.image=image` and then use `<img src=controller.image />` in the HTML. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) for the documentation.

Comment: @Beep Inside the first function of `then()`

Comment: @Weedoze yep, perfect trying now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside the *then* callback, you have to save the returned data into your $scope :

```js
$scope.GetData = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.somepage.co.uk/page/page2/objects",
            method: "POST",
            date: {},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            $scope.data = response;   // Save the returned data into your $scope
            console.log('you have received the data ');
            console.log(response);
        }, function (response) { // optional
            // failed
            console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Nice and easy, thanks. Would  '$scope.data = response' be repeated for each object im geting from the json ?

Comment: If it's the array of data you want, you can. console.log it to see if it's already the data you want or you have to look deeper in the response object(response.data, response.data.items, ...)

Comment: hmm, I just want to store 'c_name', 'max_slots' and all 'base_image' so that I may use them in my controller and print out in my angular html